# Lokalise: How to change default NSStringFormatValueTypeKey

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, lokalise

The default `NSStringFormatValueTypeKey` property in Lokalise always returns the string `li`.  In my code, the string `d`.

When exporting the modified stringsdict file from Lokalise to Github, the `NSStringFormatValueTypeKey` is always `li`.  Currently, there is no way to change this hardcoded value in the Lokalise platform.  What is a trick to change the value besides manually changing them in the stringsdict file in Xcode?  I want to change the value to `d`

Export from Lokalise:

```
<key>plural.day</key>
<dict>
      <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
      <string>%#@day@</string>
      <key>day</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>li</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string></string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
```

Desired outcome:

```
<key>plural.day</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@day@</string>
        <key>day</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d day ago</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d days ago</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the value to `d`

I'd say: Stop wanting that. `li` is correct and there's no harm in the change. Basically what's happened is that this is passed into Lokalise's own internal format which simply says "it's an integer" in a totally different way, and is then regenerated, and when that happens, it's expressed as `li` which is fine.